# Date filter not working

Tags: angularjs

Long story short, I'm trying to display a date that came from json.

This is what I tried:

```
{{ item.CreateDate | date }}
{{ item.CreateDate | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
```

This is what I get: `/Date(1413010800000)/`

I want to get `10/14/2014`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What do you get if you don't use the date filter? I'm wondering if your variable is not a date object.

Comment: if no filter I get the same... the json looks like this: `CreateDate: "/Date(1413010800000)/"`

Comment: Looks like you have `Date(1413010800000)` as a string see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QRvSPekGhxBTXPtJ9onE?p=preview try using `JSON.parse` on your value

Comment: so you are saying that the problem is with the way asp.net mvc serializes the date?

Comment: Yes, I have come across that before, I'm sure there are plenty of answers on here that can direct you in to solving that issue on the server.

Comment: Example fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
{{ item.CreateDate | msDate | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
```

And the filter

```
app.filter('msDate', function () {
  return function (item) {
    return new Date(parseInt(item.substr(6)));
  };
});
```

Thanks @Brocco.